# Windows 2003 VM drops out of domain

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-domain, workgroup

A customer of ours is cloning a domain-joined Windows 2003 VM, changes its IP but leaves it with the same hostname (using sysprep). It still retains connectivity to the same domain controller.

What they're seeing is that the cloned copy drops out of the domain and becomes part of a workgroup, while the original VM remains inside the domain.

Now, I realize that this is a configuration that simply cannot work because the domain controller cannot have two machines with the same name. I just want to make sure that we're not missing something else.

Is it expected for a Windows 2003 VM to drop out of a domain in case of two domain-joined VMs with the same name but different IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Sysprep's unattend.xml isn't setup to join the computer to the domain, it'll stick it in a workgroup.

You can confirm/configure your Sysprep settings regarding domain joins with this MS reference: [Automating the Domain Join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730845(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As it turns out, unattend.xml was set to place the VM in a workgroup.